# ActionMailer in Sneakers Rake Task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, actionmailer

I'm putting together an email scheduler/sender in a Ruby on Rails application. I am using the [Bunny](https://github.com/ruby-amqp/bunny) gem for creating a messaging queue, and I have a [Rufus](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler) scheduler that periodically puts messages into the queue. I am using a [Sneakers](https://github.com/jondot/sneakers) rake task to pull in messages from the queue whenever they are added. I start the Sneakers worker from the command line like so:

```
WORKERS=Processor rake sneakers:run
```

The code reaches the mail() function and then quits, the email template isn't even being generated. I have working email code in my normal application and I transferred the configurations over to the rake task, so I know my configurations are correct.

**app/workers/processor.rb**

```
require 'sneakers'
require 'json'
require 'action_mailer'

class Processor
  include Sneakers::Worker
  from_queue :email_queue,
        :env => 'development',
    :ack => true
  Sneakers.configure {}
  Sneakers.logger.level = Logger::ERROR

  Sneakers::Worker.configure_logger(Logger.new('/dev/null'))

  def work(msg)
    string  = msg.force_encoding("ISO-8859-1")
    hash = JSON.parse(string)
    ack!
    UserMailer.test_email(hash).deliver
  end
end
```

**app/mailer/user_mailer.rb**

```
require 'action_mailer'
require 'fog'
require 'rubygems'

class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def test_email(hash)
    @order = hash["order"]
    @currentUser = hash["user"]
    @staffCompany = hash["company"]
    mail(to: "some.email@gmail.com", from: "another.email@gmail.com", subject: 'Action Mailer')
  end
end
```

**app/views/user_mailer/test_email.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="PlainText">
      Some text goes here
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**config/environments/development.rb**

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  port: 587,
  domain: 'gmail.com',
  user_name: 'gmail account',
  password: 'password',
  authentication: 'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto: true}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**edit 1:**
Moved the template to the correct location, but the template still isn't rendering and the email isn't being sent out.

Comment: Have you checked the logs for any errors that might give a clue as to what is happening?

Comment: Just found that the template was in the wrong location, so I fixed that. When I ran it again it still isn't sending out the email, but the missing template error is gone. I see my logging right before the mail() function, then after that there is no mention of a template being rendered.

Comment: I don't know much about the gems you are using, but maybe the email is sitting in a queue somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I have switched from using a Sneakers worker that is constantly taking messages from the queue, to a scheduled rake task that takes all available messages in the queue. I don't know why the Action Mailer performs so differently in the Sneakers worker versus the Rake Task, but this is a decent workaround and there is plenty of documentation on creating a mailer rake task using Rufus. If anyone has any insight please post it as I'm still curious how to get the Sneakers worker to use the Action Mailer.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of reviving an old thread, I came across this on Google researching a similar problem. For anyone else's sake that does the same, here's a passing thought.

I noticed in your worker you call the mailer after you call ack!. [The documentation](https://github.com/jondot/sneakers/wiki/Creating-a-Worker) (see Job Control after the list) says that this breaks a reporting paradigm since the last line in the worker needs to return a certain value to manage the queue properly. I wonder if what you're seeing is a side-effect of that.

In your **app/workers/processor.rb**, Try changing:

```
  def work(msg)
    string  = msg.force_encoding("ISO-8859-1")
    hash = JSON.parse(string)
    ack!
    UserMailer.test_email(hash).deliver
  end
```

To:

```
  def work(msg)
    string  = msg.force_encoding("ISO-8859-1")
    hash = JSON.parse(string)
    UserMailer.test_email(hash).deliver
    ack!
  end
```